# How to post form, from a dynamic element

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic table that fills with a href links that each one has data element with their own value. 
There is also a form (not generated dinamically) which has an input type hidden, which will be set by link data value.

I can post the form with the hidden input value with the correct data, and the action page is loading fine, but can't receive any post data.
It seems that dinamically elements can post form but data is not being sent.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {        
      jQuery(document).on("click", ".linksollicituddetall", function() {
        var intIdSollicitud = jQuery(this).data("idsol");

        if(intIdSollicitud.toString().length > 0) {
            jQuery("#idsol").val(intIdSollicitud);
            jQuery("#frmDetallSollicitud").submit();    
        }
       });
   });

 <body>

<form id="frmDetallSollicitud" method="POST" action="DetallSollicitud.asp">
    <input type="hidden" name="idsol" id="idsol" value="-1">
</form>

</body>
```

What I want to achieve is when clicking on the link, the input type hidden fills with the data of the link, and then submit the form. In the next page (action URL) receive the post data.

Comment: The code seems fine to me and it should work. Have you debugged the code to see that the value is being set to the hidden field? How do you determine that the form does not post the value? Is the hidden field inside the form in question?

Comment: I debug it using fiddler, and the form is sent with no posting data. And also in the destination page, the Request.form is arriving void. The hidden field its in the form yes.

Comment: Please post HTML. Can't assume that the form is done correctly nor can it be assumed that `.linksollicituddetall`, `#idsol`, `#frmDetallSollicitud` are form controls. Many OPs try using value properties on divs and expect a miracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem was, that the link was launching the href before sending the form, so the problem was not preventingDefault.

The correct code is:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".linksollicituddetall", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var intIdSollicitud = jQuery(this).data("idsol");

        if(intIdSollicitud.toString().length > 0) {
            jQuery("#idsol").val(intIdSollicitud);
            jQuery("#frmDetallSollicitud").submit();    
        }
    });
```